# How could Vegans have commented on Arroway's hands?

Tags: contact

When Arroway makes contact with Vegans, the entity, at one point, says:

> "You have your mother's hands."

Now, we know that Eleanor Ann Arroway's mother died at childbirth. We also know that Vegans "downloaded" Arroway's memories to make it easier for her.

So, since Arroway had no memory of how her mother actually looked like, how could the entity know what her mother's hands looked like?

(Could this possibly be something that Theodor Arroway, Ellie's father, used to say to Ellie, which was downloaded as well, and is simply another reference as to make it easier for Arroway?)

Comment: It's all the plants they eat. It makes them very perceptive.

Comment: My guess is that it is an error that slipped through when the script was being revised into its final form.  In the novel, Arroway's mother did not die during childbirth and in fact lived on into Ellie's adulthood, so Ellie would have had many memories of her.  Really, the movie is an *hors d'oeuvre* compared to the feast that Sagan presents in the novel.  You should read it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clear implication is that this is a memory, something that her father used to say to her when she was little. In the [original source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(novel)), the conversation is very similar.

> ***“You've become a real scrapper,” he said, as if he really were her father,*** as if he were comparing his last recollections of her with her present, still incompletely developed self.
>   **He gave her hair an affectionate tousle. She remembered that from childhood also.** But **how could they, 30,000 light-years from Earth, know her father's affectionate gestures in long-ago and faraway Wisconsin?**
>   Suddenly she knew.
>   “Dreams,” she said. “Last night, when we were all dreaming, **you were inside our heads, right? You drained everything we know.”**

Answer (score 0):

I think it was intended to be that way, not an error that slipped in the script or something referring to the memory. The movie is trying to create a link of understanding between religion and science, and the fact that they know something about her mother that she can't possibly know means that there might exist a place where people's consciousness goes when they die, a heaven/hell if thought from a religious point of view.

They already made clear the dreams/memory part in that scene, why would they add another comment referring to the same thing? To me, it has a powerful meaning of things yet to be discovered through all those much more advanced civilizations.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  That's quite an ambitious theory; can you find any other evidence that supports an awareness on the part of the Vegans of a human afterlife?